# How can show that $V \cong \mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am in real trouble to prove a assignment problem of algebra. It is as follows $:$

Let $V$ be a subgroup of all invertible matrices over $\mathbb R$ consisting of diagonal matrices. Show that $V \cong \mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R^* \times \mathbb R^*$.

How can I proceed? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "all invertible matrices" do you mean "all $3\times3$ invertible matrices?

Comment: This is also my problem. It has not been mentioned in the assignment about the order of such matrices.

Comment: Well, it really can't be anything else than $GL(3,\mathbb{R}$), right? Have you tried building a map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^\ast\times\mathbb{R}^\ast\times\mathbb{R}^\ast$? There is an obvious choice.

Comment: This holds if and only if you are to look at precisely 3x3 matrices. Otherwise the group has the wrong number of elements of order two. I'm sure you can handle the 3x3 case, and otherwise the claim is wrong. So proceed with a clear conscience :-)

Comment: @B.Pasternak there is indeed an obvious map which is $\mathrm {diag} (a_1,a_2, a_3) \mapsto (a_1,a_2,a_3)$. Isn't it so?

Comment: This would be the most obvious map to me, yes. Can you prove that this is well-defined, and that it is a bijective group homomorphism?

Comment: Yeah. Sure! I can.

Comment: Good then. If you want you can write the proof once you are finished, then it can be checked, if you wish. (You can answer your own question, then the question doesn't remain unanswered).

Comment: Thanks for your help.I will answer my own question soon.